# how do i get git to push a repository i "repo sync" a month ago that has been deleted to a new repository on github to share?

Tags: android, git, repository, android-manifest, push

i did not clone this repository, I did `repo init -u http:// repository_name/manifest.git` 3 months ago. I was still learning different things as a beginner. The user who's repo i used has since deleted it. I now am at the point where I have something to share but I do not know how to push it to github. Most definately a new repository of my own so i do not have to worry about losing it again to sync from. how do i do this? using git doesnt seem to push all the files and leaves some folders empty. afterwards if i do i do a `$ git status`, I will recieve errors of .git in certain folders which i no longer have the repository to. How do i do all of this? I want a new repository that I can commit fully to and share. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

On github, create a new repo: see https://github.com/new

The add the new remote: `git remote add github git@github.com:<username>/<repo>`

then: `git push github`